# Typescript Error 2307 for relative imports

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, babeljs

I am receiving an error when trying to use relative imports in my React Native expo project:
`Cannot find module 'constants/Colors' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

My app compiles but I still get this TS error.

here is my tsconfig:

```
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  },
  "paths": {
    "components/*": ["components/*"],
    "constants/*": ["constants/*"]
  }
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Neither SO or chatGPT have helped.I have tried deleting node_modules & running `npm i`, I have restarted TS server and my config seems right. My files are definitely in the right place and typed right.

Comment: if you use typescript did you install the type for the librarie you install ?

Comment: I am just importing an object of my own creation from the constants/Colors.ts file

Comment: ok I see but i can't really tell as what you show, you may need to show more code for the issue in order for other people to help eventually, did you try also to clear the cache on expo?

Comment: I'm not sure if expo cache is the problem? Surely this is a VS code/typescript problem? What other code would you like to see?